# React native fs iOS not showing files in the document directory

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am working on a react native project. I need to store the captured images in the custom folder.

I am using react native fs library for that. I am able to create the image in the desired directory but I am not able to see those images in my iphones' file directory.

Here is my code I am using to store the images.

```
 async moveAttachment(capturedImagePath) {

    $filePathDir = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/myapp/myfilename`;
    $filePath = `${$filePathDir }/myfilename.png`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        RNFS.mkdir(filePathDir)
        .then(() => {
            RNFS.moveFile(capturedImagePath, filePath )
            .then(() => resolve(dirPictures))
            .catch(error => reject(error));
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
}
```

I am able to see the image in my simulator's document directory but not able to see in the iPhone > files directory.

Please help me to figure this out.

Comment: The file will be stored in the document directory of the app. How are you checking that it isn't there? Because if you are looking in the `Files` application you won't see it there.

Comment: @Andrew I need to store the files in the local storage so that I can access them without using my app also.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should be able to enable it by updating your `Info.plist`. You need to add two keys:

`UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` should both be added and set to `YES`.

- `UIFileSharingEnabled`: Application supports iTunes file sharing
- `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`: Supports opening documents in place

This will allow your `DocumentsDirectory` to be opened in iTunes and it should also allow you to share your files via the `Files` application.

[image: info.plist]

You can read more about `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW13)

> In iOS 11 and later, if both this key and the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key
>   are `YES`, the local file provider grants access to all the documents in
>   the app’s `Documents` directory. These documents appear in the `Files`
>   app, and in a document browser. Users can open and edit these document
>   in place.

Note that **any** item you save in the `Documents` directory will be accessible.

Comment: Uffff, your answer is a daysaver, thank you! Works for me!

Comment: thank you that was the only thing that worked for me .

Comment: Still valid on 2023, thank you
If you add them from code:
        <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
 <true/>
 <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
 <true/>

Answer (score 1):

The answer @Andrew provided still working on iOS 17
Remember only to set the Directory to the right place
const basePath =
(Platform.OS === 'android'
? RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath
***: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath);***