# react-native-fs on iOS doesn't show the downloaded file in the Files app

Tags: ios, react-native, filesystems, ios15, react-native-fs

I'm trying to download a file using `react-native-fs`.

The file downloads but I can't see it in the Files app on the device.

Here is the code:

```js
const RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
const directory = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
const filePath = `${directory}/${fileName}`;

RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl: fileURL,
    toFile: filePath,
}).promise.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626359/react-native-fs-ios-not-showing-files-in-the-document-directory) but it works up to iOS 14 and my project is for iOS 15.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The answer you linked to is still valid for iOS 15

Comment: @Paulw11 In my case it still doesn't work, is it because it's a simulator?